# Restrict lambda resolver to owner for GraphQL API using Amplify

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

In my `schema.graphql` file I have the following:

```
type Floorplan @model @auth(rules: [
        { allow: private, operations: [read], provider: userPools },
        { allow: owner, provider: userPools }
    ]) @aws_cognito_user_pools {
    id: ID! @primaryKey
    name: String!
    bedrooms: Int!
}

input FloorplanInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    bedrooms: Int!
}

type Mutation {
    floorplanLambda(input: FloorplanInput): Floorplan 
    @function(name: "floorplanLambda-${env}")
    @aws_cognito_user_pools
}
```

I created the lambda function to perform custom validation before updating.
The problem is that any authenticated user can update other users' floor plans. I thought adding `@aws_cognito_user_pools` would resolve this, but it doesn't.

**Question:** What do I need to add to lock down the `floorplanLambda` function so that it can only be successfully called by the owner of the Floorplan model?

When calling `floorplanLambda` I receive the error: "Not Authorized to access floorplanLambda on type Floorplan".  I'm making the call with authMode `AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS`.

For some more context, I followed this tutorial to create the custom mutation lambda function: https://www.theclouddeveloper.io/use-lambda-resolvers-in-your-graph-ql-api-with-aws-amplify

Answer (score 0):

So according to the response to my GitHub issue, this workflow is not currently supported. You can follow it here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/528#issuecomment-1157894170

A workaround was provided by:

> ...setting the auth rule to private and then perform
> validation in the lambda function...

I was thinking to create a custom auth function and then chain it in front of my custom mutation.  Not sure if that will work but I'll report back once I've made some progress.